# Problem with join two lists by linq

Tags: development, document-library, visual-studio, linq

I wanna join two list and fill drop down list by specific column but i have error in join query
 note:c.user_id is lookup field

my code

```
lst.DataSource = (from c in dc.Complainant
                     join u in dc.User_collec
                     on c.User_id equals u.User_id
                     select new { m=u.Title }).ToList();
```

the Error is The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: I think the solution is easy but i need it :(

Comment: There is no solutions !! why :( :(

Answer (score 1):

If your lookup is not of multi type, something like this is worth a shot:

```
lst.DataSource = (from SPListItem c in dc.Complainant
    where c["User_id"] != null
    join SPListItem u in dc.User_collec
    on new SPFieldLookupValue(c["User_id"] as string).LookupValue
    equals u.User_id
    select new { m=u.Title }).ToList();
```

The differens is mainly the extraction of the value from the Lookup column, and that it takes in account cases where the c.User_id is null